# calculating the area of an irregular shape from coordinates in a csv file using python

Tags: python, csv, area

i am using Python to import a csv file with coordinates in it, passing it to a list and using the contained data to calculate the area of each irregular figure. The data within the csv file looks like this.

```
ID  Name    DE1 DN1 DE2 DN2 DE3 DN3
88637   Zack Fay    -0.026841782    -0.071375637    0.160878583 -0.231788845    0.191811833 0.396593863 
88687   Victory Greenfelder 0.219394372 -0.081932907    0.053054879 -0.048356016    
88737   Lynnette Gorczany   0.043632299 0.118916157 0.005488698 -0.268612073    
88787   Odelia Tremblay PhD 0.083147337 0.152277791 -0.039216388    0.469656787 -0.21725977 0.073797219
```

The code i am using is below - however it brings up an IndexError: as the first line doesn't have data in all columns. Is there a way to write the csv file so it only uses the colums with data in them ?

```
import csv
import math

def main():
    try:
    # ask user to open a file with coordinates for 4 points
        my_file = raw_input('Enter the Irregular Differences file name and location: ')

        file_list = []

        with open(my_file, 'r') as my_csv_file:
            reader = csv.reader(my_csv_file)
            print 'my_csv_file: ', (my_csv_file)
            reader.next()

            for row in reader:
                print row
                file_list.append(row)

        all = calculate(file_list)
        save_write_file(all)

    except IOError:
        print 'File reading error, Goodbye!'
    except IndexError:
        print 'Index Error, Check Data'


# now do your calculations on the 'data' in the file.

def calculate(my_file):

return_list = []

    for row in my_file:

        de1 = float(row[2])
        dn1 = float(row[3])
        de2 = float(row[4])
        dn2 = float(row[5])
        de3 = float(row[6])
        dn3 = float(row[7])
        de4 = float(row[8])
        dn4 = float(row[9])
        de5 = float(row[10])
        dn5 = float(row[11])
        de6 = float(row[12])
        dn6 = float(row[13])
        de7 = float(row[14])
        dn7 = float(row[15])
        de8 = float(row[16])
        dn8 = float(row[17])
        de9 = float(row[18])
        dn9 = float(row[19])

        area_squared = abs((dn1 * de2) - (dn2 * de1)) + ((de3 * dn4) - (dn3 * de4)) + ((de5 * dn6) - (de6 * dn5)) + ((de7 * dn8) - (dn7 * de8)) + ((dn9 * de1) - (de9 * dn1))
        area = area_squared / 2

        row.append(area)
        return_list.append(row)
    return return_list


def save_write_file(all):

    with open('output_task4B.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(["ID", "Name", "de1", "dn1", "de2", "dn2", "de3", "dn3", "de4", "dn4", "de5", "dn5", "de6", "dn6", "de7", "dn7", "de8", "dn8", "de9", "dn9", "Area"])
        writer.writerows(all)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any suggestions

Comment: It appears your csv file has no commas. Is that true, or did you copy and paste a spreadsheet screen instead of the actual csv data?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appears to be in the `calculate` function.

You are trying to access various indexes of `row` without first confirming they exist. One naive approach might be to consider the values to be zero if they are not present, except that:

```
+ ((dn9 * de1) - (de9 * dn1)
```

is an attempt to wrap around, and this might invalidate your math since they would go to zero.

A better approach is probably to use a slice of the row, and use the sequence-iterating approach instead of trying to require a certain number of points. This lets your code fit the data.

```
coords = row[2:]   # skip id and name

assert len(coords) % 2 == 0, "Coordinates must come in pairs!"

prev_de = coords[-2]
prev_dn = coords[-1]
area_squared = 0.0

for de, dn in zip(coords[:-1:2], coords[1::2]):
    area_squared += (de * prev_dn) - (dn * prev_de)
    prev_de, prev_dn = de, dn

area = abs(area_squared) / 2
```

The next problem will be dealing with variable length output. I'd suggest putting the area before the coordinates. That way you know it's always column 3 (or whatever).

Comment: Thanks for your assistance @AustinHastings it works now!